# When I run a program over ssh, why does stdin stop echoing back?

Tags: putty, stdin

When I run a particular program on my server using putty and I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop it, my stdin stops echoing back to me at the command line.
So for example, after running the program and stopping it, if I type ls I cannot see the characters ls, but I can see the directory listing.
What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### stty sane

Probably the program sets some terminal settings (see `man stty`) and when you interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the program does not catch the interrupt and clean up (i.e restore to normal) the terminal settings but just exits. It may be just the `stty echo` (echo input characters) setting that needs resetting, but it is probably others too.

**Just use the command `stty sane` to restore sanity to your terminal settings.**

Alternatively you should be able to use `stty -g > settings.stty`to save current terminal settings before running your program. After interrupting the program, use `` stty `cat settings.stty` `` to restore those specific settings. Try `stty sane`first, it should do all you need.